# Vue js stop event from bubling

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 nested divs:

```
<div @click ="action1">
      <div @click.prevent ="action2($event)"></div>
</div>
```

I want when clicking on second div only action 2 to be fired:
I tried to use this (but didn't help):

```
action2(event){
      event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

`<div @click.stop >`worked for me